# query select equaled data on three columns of table with four columns and ignore one

Tags: sql, database, select

I have table have four columns like (right ,left ,up ,down) I want to build query that show equaled data on three of the four columns;

example:
| id | right | left    | up     | down   |

|:---|:------:|:-----:|:------:|  -----:|

| 1  | street |hospital|coffee |building|

| 2  | house  |hospital|coffee |building|

| 3  | road   | bus    |coffee |sign    |

| 4  | house  |hospital|coffee |sign    |

| 5  | car    |road    |coffee |sign    |

the result should be like:

| id | right | left | up | down |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | street | hospital | coffee | building |
| 2 | house | hospital | coffee | building |

id number 3 and 5 not included because every column should equal it's self

is that query correct

```
select t.* from test_table t where 
     (t.right,t.left,t.up) in (select t.right,t.left,t.up from test_table t group by t.right,t.left,t.up having count(*)>1)
 or (t.right,t.left,t.down) in (select t.right,t.left,t.down from test_table t group by t.right,t.left,t.down having count(*)>1)
 or (t.right,t.up,t.down) in (select t.right,t.up,t.down from test_table t group by t.right,t.up,t.down having count(*)>1)
 or (t.left,t.up,t.down) in (select t.left,t.up,t.down from test_table t group by t.left,t.up,t.down having count(*)>1)
 and t.mud_id=285 order by t.right,t.left,t.up,t.down  ;
```

if it correct it's go in loop without result for more than 10m waiting
if not
please what is the correct query to get the result

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: oracle database

Comment: That query does work on Oracle, but needed to remove the mid_id = 285 statement. It returns rows for id's 1, 2 and 4.

Comment: how 4 come in result could you modify the query please

Comment: 4 and 2 are a match, no?

Comment: didn't focus sorry

Comment: why it's stay in loop without show query result
is it because the data more than 2 million records

Comment: Another reason why I don't like Oracle. I don't know how to improve that query, but perhaps try to break it out into 4 separate queries that insert data into another table. Then select from that table.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are some assumptions to be made on how how to order and/or organize the results, you may use the query below to identify each matching pair.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ID INT, [right] VARCHAR(20), [left] varchar(20), up 
varchar(20), down varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,'street','hospital','coffee','building'),
(2,'house','hospital','coffee','building'),
(3,'road','bus','coffee','sign'),
(4,'house','hospital','coffee','sign'),
(5,'car','road','coffee','sign'),
(6,'street','road','coffee','sign')

SELECT
    T1.ID AS MatchID1, 
    T2.ID AS MatchID2   
FROM
    @T T1
    INNER JOIN @T T2 ON T1.ID <> T2.ID
GROUP BY
    T1.ID, T2.ID
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN T1.[right] = T2.[right] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN T1.[left] = T2.[left] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN T1.up = T2.up THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN T1.down = T2.down THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 3


MatchID1    MatchID2
2           1
1           2
4           2
2           4
6           5
5           6
```

A trick to bring back matches by first occurrence using:

```
INNER JOIN @T T2 ON T1.ID > T2.ID

MatchID1    MatchID2
1           2
2           4
5           6
```